# Use rollup to build js file which import an external module that has no exports declaration, the output file cannot be load

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

For example, I have js file as following:

```
// index.js in current folder
require('external');
console.log('zzzzzzzz');
```

And I have an external module in my node_modules folder just like following:

```
// external.js in node_modules folder
consoler.log('eeeeeeee');
// there has no any exports define.
```

Note: This module is just an example, actual module is for browser, it define a JQuery plugin. For an example, you can reference to 'bootstrap-switch' NPM package.

Back to my question, I wrote a rollup.config.js file like following to build my `index.js` file to UMD module.

```
// rollup.config.js in current folder
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  entry: 'index.js',
  dest: 'bundle.js',
  format: 'umd',
  external: ['external'],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({
      skip: 'external'
    }),
    commonjs()
  ],
  moduleName: 'test'
}
```

In this config, I define 'external' module as external module to avoid rollup to bundle it into bundle.js.

when I run `rollup -c` in terminal. I got a bundle.js file as following:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory(require('external')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['external'], factory) :
    (global.test = factory(global.external));
}(this, (function (external) { 'use strict';

external = 'default' in external ? external['default'] : external; // Crack here

console.log('zzzzzzzz');

var index = {

};

return index;

})));
```

When I load bundle.js into browser through RequireJS, I will got an exception on Ln 6, because 'external' parameter is undefined (external module did't exports anything).

Anyone help me? Thanks.